# java script error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>"

Tags: javascript

This is my code, When i run it in lambda. It works fine but when i run it on my local server it's giving error [line 22: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>]

This is my first JS. :)

can someone please help me to understand this error.

Thanks!

```
"use strict";
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const data = querystring.stringify({
    'input' :  'test is passed'
});

const options = {
    hostname: 'abc.xyz',
    port: 443,
    path: '/DEV/-testresult',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'x-api-key' : 'xxxxxx',
        'X-Amz-Invocation-Type' : 'Event'
    }

};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    let body = '';
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
        // If we know it's JSON, parse it
        if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
        }
    });
});

req.on('error');
req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
req.end();
```

Comment: `other location` - what location? Paris? New York?

Comment: `Looks like error is regarding "=>"` - looks like you use internet explorer? or maybe a **very** old nodejs

Comment: What does running `$ node -v` give you?

Answer (score 0):

Use function instead on Arrow function. it will work.

```
    const req = https.request(options, **function**(res){
    let body = '';
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers:', JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Successfully processed HTTPS response');
        // If we know it's JSON, parse it
        if (res.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
        }
    });
});
```